# Pinch gesture in Polymer 2.0 web component

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I wonder how i can implement pinch gesture in Polymer2.0

I looked in hammer.js also but i hav no clue how to integrate it with Polymer 2.0

Comment: if you want to use hammer.js then simply implement it like in all other sites. there is no difference. You don't need anything special for it.

Comment: I already tired but not able get any event from HammerJs
ready() {
        super.ready();

        var mc = new Hammer.Manager(this.$.wrapper);
        mc.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0 }) );
        mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }) );

        mc.on("pan", ()=>{console.log('pan')});
        mc.on("doubletap", ()=>{console.log('tap')});
      }

Comment: for me, it's working without any problems. Do you have any console errors? other thing is that `ready` function in `Polymer 2.0` isn't reliable. try to use hammer firstly in console to see, if is the problem in timing. (bad sync)..